# Python Pywinauto is it possible to Close a instance of Application connection ? I dont see any attribute as close or Disconnect with Application

Tags: python, testing, automation, pywinauto

is it possible to close an active instance of connection ? like how we are connecting to an active instance using app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r'D:\Asem\bin64\AUT.exe') like this I want to close the instance via code and again connect whenever I required to validate the UI element , something like "Application(backend="uia").disconnectOrClose(path=r'D:\Asem\bin64\AUT.exe')"

Note:iam not talking about closing the application(AUT) here, just the connection which we established via Application.connect

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the application running, just do `del app` for `app` object. If you want to kill/close the app, use `app.kill(soft=False)`. With `soft=True` it will try to close the app gracefully otherwise it is hard kill.

Comment: how can I use del for my app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r'D:\Asem\bin64\AUT.exe') , ?                              I tried self.app = Application(backend=AccessMethod).connect(path=AUTpath)
        self.prod_Idle = self.app.window(title='production Idle')
        self.closeapp = self.app.del app                                                                                 
 but this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Sorry , I got it now what u said to delete . in my case it deletes app instance if I use del app . so again I have to declare the app instance .

Comment: There is nothing special for connection in the app object except app.process (it’s process ID). Maybe you want to set it to None? Not sure I got the question.

Comment: In order to avoid having active connection all the time with AUT , I wanted to disconnect the connection whenever I want , but still application should be running , so that if I am running more tests I can avoid timeout issue with our application thats idea here

Comment: A timeout issue shouldn’t be related to several app objects in different Python processes. This is not a database-like connection. Just app object has a correct pid. There is no any interactions if app object is not used. So I don’t see any problem with keeping an app connection if it’s not active.

Comment: A problem could happen when two or more tests are trying to test the same app instance or even several app instances on the same active desktop. But handling this is a CI task, not a pywinauto one.